# Angular CLI bundling issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have started an Angular2 project using Angular-cli, everything is in working in order when I run ng-serve.

My problem is when view source in the browser I can see that it injects three bundles scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

But when I try and find them in my source there not there.

My end goal is to create a library of specific angular2 components that will sit in AWS-S3 as a single bundle script and a CSS bundle. Once i have this I would be including the library into multiple projects.

Comment: I know for myself, I got a lot more control over exactly how things are bundled when I stopped using the CLI and started using Webpack directly. I know the CLI uses webpack, but it seems to do its best to be "turnkey", and hide the webpack nitty gritty build details from you. When you use webpack directly you get tremendous control over the process. There's a learning curve, but nothing extreme. Unless I'm doing a quick prototype I don't use the CLI at all anymore.

Comment: @TimConsolazio related: [ng eject](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng eject` to expose webpack configuration. In that way you can modify it.

Comment: Trying to but it looks like i have to update angular cli

Comment: Can you reverse an eject @Serginho?

Comment: @Johnwilliams I think it has been introduced in angular-cli RC-0. And No, it can't be reverted. But you have to revert package.json, .angular-cli.json, tsconfig.app.json and delete webpack.config.js

Comment: @Johnwilliams so, yes, it can be reverted... by doing those things :)

Comment: `ng eject` has been disabled :( This is really annoying